# Process analyses using bupaR

Tags: r, plot, dplyr, lubridate, business-process-management

I am basically looking at three types of analyses on the patients data which comes along with installing the bupaR package:

1. Plot for throughput time along with filters.
2. Plot for case frequency along with filters.
3. Plot for activity frequency along with filters.

I tried this code for throughput time from the website bupar.net:

```
library(bupaR)
library(edeaR)
library(eventdataR)
library(processmapR)
library(processmonitR)
library(xesreadR)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

patients %>% throughput_time("log") %>%plot()
```

but it is throwing an error. Please help, thanks.

Comment: What is the error? Are all the extra packages really necessary to reproduce this? Are there any masking of functions?

Comment: Error in if (level == "log") { : argument is of length zero

Comment: try yourself, here is the link: http://bupar.net/exploring.html

Comment: @Roman Luštrik, please help, I really am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Please answer my three questions first. Keep in mind that my primary goal is not to answer your question, but to teach you how to debug your code. Teach the man to fish sort of thing...

Comment: Error in if (level == "log") { : argument is of length zero, this is the error, No, not all packages I think are necessary, but I need them for other purpose. There is not masking of any functions.

Comment: Please review how [stackoverflow works](https://stackoverflow.com/help). You need to put everything pertinent to your question in the question itself. Comment section is not really made to handle this. Please water down your question to absolutely bare minimum which still demonstrates the problem you're having.